# Selenium nested li div menu select() or click() python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, webdriver

## topMenuItem4 > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(6) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)

I have tried a variety of methods to accomplish this but I so far have not been able to select or click the provisioning server link.

Tried this:
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#topMenuItem4 > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(6) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)').click()

and this:

browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'menu-item') and (contains(.,'topMenuItem4'))]//div[contains(@class,'Provisioning Server')]")

Here is a capture of the drop down menu

http://screencast.com/t/81EQFAO7c

Here is the source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Polycom - SoundPoint IP 450 Configuration Utility</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main_page.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/page_content.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main_page.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/page_content.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/configurator.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <div id="logohdr">
        <img src="images/logo.png"/>
        <span class="leftBordered">
          SoundPoint IP 450
        </span>
      </div>
      <div id="langHeader">
        <span textId="122"> </span>
        <select id="langaugeId">
          <option value="en-in">English Internal (en-in)</option>
          <option value="zh-cn">简体中文 (zh-cn)</option>
          <option value="da-dk">Dansk (da-dk)</option>
          <option value="nl-nl">Nederlands (nl-nl)</option>
          <option value="en-us">English (en-us)</option>
          <option value="fr-fr">Français (fr-fr)</option>
          <option value="de-de">Deutsch (de-de)</option>
          <option value="it-it">Italiano (it-it)</option>
          <option value="ja-jp">日本語 (ja-jp)</option>
          <option value="ko-kr">한국어 (ko-kr)</option>
          <option value="no-no">Norsk (no-no)</option>
          <option value="pl-pl">Polski (pl-pl)</option>
          <option value="pt-br">Português (pt-br)</option>
          <option value="ru-ru">Русский (ru-ru)</option>
          <option value="sl-si">Slovenski (sl-si)</option>
          <option value="es-es">Español (es-es)</option>
          <option value="sv-se">Svenska (sv-se)</option>
          <option value="zh-cht">繁體中文 (zh-cht)</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
      <ul id="utility-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="rightBordered">
            <span textId="677"> </span>
            Admin
          </a>
        </li>
        <li src="logout">
          <a href="login.htm">
            <span textId="678"> </span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="primary-nav">
        <li src="home.htm" id="topMenuItem1">
          <a href="javascript:;">
            <span textId="96"> </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li src="simpleSetup.htm" id="topMenuItem2">
          <a href="javascript:;">
            <span textId="201"> </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item" id="topMenuItem3">
          <a href="javascript:;">
            <span textId="190"> </span>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li src="datetimeConf.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="57"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="sampConf.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="218"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="bgConfMedGray.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="24"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="presence.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="534"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="othersConf.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="171"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item" id="topMenuItem4">
          <a href="javascript:;">
            <span textId="242"> </span>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li src="browConf.htm" checkFeature="MB">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="146"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="logConf.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="135"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="applConf.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="8"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="codecprefConf.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="12"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="audioCodecProfConf.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;"><span textId="9"> </span> Codec Profiles</a>
            </li>
            <li src="provConf.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="316"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="syslogConf.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="533"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item-2">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="152"> </span>
              </a>
              <ul>
                <li src="qosConf.htm">
                  <a href="javascript:;">
                    <span textId="197"> </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li src="rtpConf.htm">
                  <a href="javascript:;">
                    <span textId="204"> </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li src="natConf.htm">
                  <a href="javascript:;">
                    <span textId="150"> </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li src="tcpConf.htm">
                  <a href="javascript:;">
                    <span textId="253"> </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li src="sslSecurityConf.htm">
                  <a href="javascript:;">
                    <span textId="228"> </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li src="ethernetConf.htm">
                  <a href="javascript:;">
                    <span textId="329"> </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li src="pttConf.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="473"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="sipConf.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="531"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item-3" src="reg_1.htm" displaySubMenuInLeftPanel="1">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="125"> </span>
              </a>
              <ul>
                <li src="reg_1.htm">
                  <a href="javascript:;"><span textId="123"> </span> 1</a>
                </li>
                <li src="reg_2.htm">
                  <a href="javascript:;"><span textId="123"> </span> 2</a>
                </li>
                <li src="reg_3.htm">
                  <a href="javascript:;"><span textId="123"> </span> 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li src="userAccountConf.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="271"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="phoneLockConf.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="178"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item" id="topMenuItem5">
          <a href="javascript:;">
            <span textId="62"> </span>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li src="viewlogs.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="283"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item" id="topMenuItem6">
          <a href="javascript:;">
            <span textId="276"> </span>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li src="importexportconf.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="111"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="phoneBackupRestore.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="177"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="upgrade.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="246"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="Soft_Key_configTool.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="285"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="Line_Key_configTool.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="536"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="restartPhone.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="214"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li src="rebootPhone.htm">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                <span textId="209"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="breadcrumbs">
      <p/>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="nav" class="nav">
        <div id="phoneimage">
          <p/>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div>
              <span textId="673"> </span>
            </div>
            <ul/>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="content" class="content">
        <div id="pageContent">
          <p/>
        </div>
        <div id="btnCnt_static_pg">
          <div id="buttonContent" class="button-group">
            <button class="button gray medium" onclick="resetForm()" toolTipId="271">
              <span textId="584"/>
            </button>
            <button class="button gray medium" onclick="resetToDefaults()" toolTipId="272">
              <span textId="1002"/>
            </button>
            <button class="button gray medium" onclick="viewModifications()" toolTipId="273">
              <span textId="1003"/>
            </button>
            <button class="button gray medium" onclick="submitForm()" toolTipId="274">
              <span textId="574"/>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="supp-info" class="supp-info">
        <ul class="tree">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="selected">
              <span textId="674"> </span>
            </a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div style="height:130px; overflow-y: scroll;"/>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:;">
              <span textId="675"> </span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:;">
              <span textId="676"> </span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="modalDialog"> </div>
    <div id="darken"> </div>
    <span id="showStartPage" style="display:none;">
      
    </span>
    <div class="popup" id="popupdlg" style="display:none">
      <div class="top-bar">
        <img src="images/popup_close.png" id="popupimgclose" width="16" height="16" align="right" class="popup-closer"/>
      </div>
      <div class="popup-content">
        <p/>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-popup-actions">
        <p/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span id="isChinesePhone" style="display:none">
      0
    </span>
    <div class="previewpopup" id="previewpopupdlg" style="display:none"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so, what are they? What browser is this?

Comment: Firefox is the browser I'm using, no errors unless it can't find a hidden element depending on what method I try. The actionchain that was suggested seems to work but click and hold on this menu only drags the image/item that was originally clicked you can't navigate this menu by clicking and holding manually or using arrows which makes me think it has to be a hover.

Comment: Also this isn't all the things I have tried, I have spent a couple days playing with syntax and different comamnds.  I can use browser.get(http://192.168.0.136:2006/provConf.htm) which brings up the form but then there is no submit button as the form is loaded inside a frame when manually selecting from the menu.  If there is a way to send a command like: submit()  <button original-title="Applies changed settings on all pages to the phone." param1="Provisioning Server" class="button gray medium" onclick="submitForm()" tooltipid="274">
              <span textid="574">Save</span></button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following CSS should work: `li[src='provConf.html'] a`.

I'm also not sure if linkText would work, but I think it is much more descriptive if it does work.

Finally, because it is a dropdown menu, it make require action chaining like Richard said.

Comment: So far my attempts at using linkText have failed I believe its because of the :hidden attribute, I can find linkText on the default page that is not :hidden but when I try to search for anything in the menu it returns a Unable to locate element exception.  I am not entirely sure where I would put the li[src='provConf.html'] but I appreciate the help and will try to work it out.

Comment: It's CSS.  So `browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li[src='provConf.html'] a")` That CSS means: find an `li` element that has a `src` attribute of `provConf.html` and then find it's first `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

I think for something like this you're going to need to use python ActionChains.  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

It'll probably end up looking something like:

```
ActionChains(browser).click_and_hold(on_element=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#topMenuItem4')).click(on_element=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#topMenuItem4 > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(6) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)')).perform()
```

Comment: I think ActionChains may be part of the answer thanks very much for the reply!  click_and_hold is not going to work but I am looking for an alternative to simulate hover.

Comment: I was looking at action chains but I get an error when I try to use move_to_element instead of click_and_hold any ideas?