# python selenium: element not visible in [weird] dropdown to be clicked

Tags: python, selenium

There are two dropdown element code: one is standard option-select and the other is made of div, ul, li elements.

And somehow both are used to select a dropdown element via javascript...

Problem is selenium is not able to click the element and throws not visible exception.....

See the dropdown box here: [Its below "Top 5" tab]
http://www.oddsbox.com/baseball/mlb/record/section.odd

Following solutions don't help either:
[Python Selenium: Find object attributes using xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579061/python-selenium-find-object-attributes-using-xpath)
[selecting element in python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244589/selecting-element-in-python-selenium)
[Selenium nested li div menu select() or click() python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394479/selenium-nested-li-div-menu-select-or-click-python)
[how to select custom dropdown list element from selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228418/how-to-select-custom-dropdown-list-element-from-selenium)

Comment: which one you are talking about? the page is in Korean. Can you be more specific? Where is your own code?

Comment: Could you share your code which have tried as well??

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you'd post your code, so we can see a bit clearer what's happening. 
Also admitted, I did not check all of your links to see everything that doesn't work. However my guess is this:

*If you get an `ElementNotVisible` exception, then you should probably make your element visible before selecting it.*

In this case I'd forget about the selecting commands and all and just :
- click on the element to open and reveal the menu and then
- click on the desired element inside that list.

Looks something like :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ctmSelectBox4_wrap']/button").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ctmSelectBox4_wrap']/div/ol/li[6]/label/span").click()
```

I personally detest these ugly xpaths (especially for maintainability), and probably would change that somehow, but that's not the scope of this question.

Hope that helps!

Comment: that was perfect....thank you...I guess I didn't consider "/button" part and also I was trying to select an element in li with an id instead of directly li[x]......[Is it possible to select "li" directly with id of its input element?] I guess not....so may be that was a problem....anyways...appreciate it...

Comment: Hi there, glad it helped you!  Good luck !

Comment: If your question is answered you can select that answer to show other people that this Q has an answer, which might be useful for other people looking out there. Thanks!